# How to check if x value exists in SML List

Tags: list, functional-programming, sml, ml

I need to write an SML function that takes in as input a list of tuples (x and y coordinates) and an integer value. The function needs to return true if the integer is an x value in the list and false otherwise. For example if the list was:

`val list = [(1,1),(2,4),(3,9),(4,16)];`

The function would behave as follows:

```
memberOf(2, list) = true
memberOf(4, list) = true
memberOf(9, list) = false
```

Can somebody help me write a function that accomplishes this? I only need to test if the x value is in the list, the y value of the tuple is unimportant.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to modify a basic memberOf function that checks if a value exists in an integer list. What I am struggling on is getting that function to check an x value in a list of tuples instead of just an integer list.

Comment: You could give your best attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
fun member_of (item, list) = List.exists (fn (x,y) => x = item) list
```

Comment: Should the anonymous function be just `fn x => x = item`?

Comment: No; the function passed to `List.exists` operates over elements of the list, and those elements are pairs.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. Didn't realize the list elements were pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the first argument of your tuple using `#1 tuple` and the second one with `#2 tuple`. So you check if the item exists either as the first argument or the second of the tuple list until you reach the end of your list.

```
(* fn : int * (int * int) list -> bool *)
fun exists_in (item: int, mylist: (int*int) list) =
    if null mylist
    then false
    else if #1 (hd mylist) = item orelse #2 (hd mylist) = item
    then true
    else exists_in (item, tl mylist)
```